# Como llamar a un qdialog varias veces pero que siempre empiece desde los valores por defecto?

Tags: python, pyqt

Tengo un QMainWindow desde el que llamo a un Qdialog, el problema es que utilizo el Qdialog para obtener datos, todo funciona bien cuando se utiliza por primera vez, pero al utilizarlo de nuevo, si no introduzco nuevos valores y simplemente lo cierro, me retorna los últimos valores retornados. Cuando lo llamo desde MainWindow lo hago así:

```
self.dialogo=secundal.buscar_cups(resultado,resp)
self.dialogo.exec_()
cod,desc=secundal.buscar_cups(resultado,resp).retorno()
```

lo que tengo en el archivo secundal es lo siguiente:

```
import sys
from busqueda_cups import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import os
import MySQLdb

id_consulta=''
descripcion=''


class buscar_cups(QtGui.QDialog):
def __init__(self,resultado,num_filas):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.ventana = Ui_Dialog()
    self.ventana.setupUi(self)

    self.ventana.tableWidget.setRowCount(num_filas)
    for i in range(0,len(resultado)):
        for j in range(0,2):
            self.ventana.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(resultado[i][j])))
    self.connect(self.ventana.tableWidget,QtCore.SIGNAL('cellDoubleClicked (int,int)'),self.seleccion)

def seleccion(self):
    global id_consulta,descripcion
    id_consulta=''
    descripcion=''
    cod,desc=self.ventana.tableWidget.selectedItems()
    id_consulta=cod.text()
    descripcion=desc.text()
    self.close()


def retorno(self):
    return id_consulta,descripcion
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `id_consulta` y `descripcion` son **variables globales** y su valor se conserva entre instancias de `buscar_cups`... No uses variables globales, haz que ambas sean atributos de instancia.

Comment: La verdad soy nueva en esto, y lo que quiero es retornar valores al MainWindow, y probando, la única manera que me funcionó fue como lo tengo programado. Podría porfavor explicarme un poco mas a que se refiere con que sean atributos de instancia?

Answer (score 0):

El retorno del método `retorno` (valga la redundancia) depende del valor de las variables `id_consulta` y `descripcion`.

Estas variables son variables globales al módulo `secundal`, cuando el módulo es importado también es ejecutado por lo que se crean ambas variables apuntando a cadenas vacías. A partir de este momento todas las posibles instancias de la clase `buscar_cups` van a compartir estas variables y su modificación afecta a todas las instancias o futuras instancias de la clase o a cualquier objeto que las use en ese módulo.

Es decir, cuando importas el módulo sendas variables globales son inicializadas a una cadena vacía, cuando instancias `buscar_cups` por primera vez si esta modifica sus valores mediante el método `seleccion`, estos cambios se mantienen para la próxima instancia de la clase.

Esta es una de las razones por las que existe ese mantra de que las variables globales son "perversas", la solución en tu caso es simplemente hacer que ambas variables sean atributos de instancia, creadas e inicializadas en el `__init__` y por tanto propias para cada instancia de la clase.

```
import sys
from busqueda_cups import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import os
import MySQLdb



class BuscarCups(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, resultado, num_filas, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BuscarCups, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id_consulta = ''
        self.descripcion = ''
        self.ventana = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ventana.setupUi(self)

        self.ventana.tableWidget.setRowCount(num_filas)
        for i in range(0,len(resultado)):
            for j in range(0,2):
                self.ventana.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(resultado[i][j])))
        self.connect(self.ventana.tableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('cellDoubleClicked (int,int)'), self.seleccion)

    def seleccion(self):
        cod, desc = self.ventana.tableWidget.selectedItems()
        self.id_consulta = cod.text()
        self.descripcion = desc.text()
        self.close()

    def retorno(self):
        return self.id_consulta, self.descripcion
```

Por otro lado, en tu ventana principal no debes crear una nueva instancia para llamar a `retorno`:

```
dialogo = secundal.BuscarCups(resultado, resp)
dialogo.exec_()  # Dialogo modal
cod, desc = dialogo.retorno()
```

Comment: Muchisimas  gracias, me funciona a la perfeccion. Me quedó todo muy claro.